# Query/sort reference of reference in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Hopefully I can explain this well.

I have 3 Model types in play here: Users, Products, and Stores. What I'm after is a sorted list of Stores, per user, based on how many Products they've added from that Store. So basically "show me this User's top Stores".

pseudo-schemas:

```
var User = {
  name: String
};

var Store = {
  name: String
};

var Product = {
  title: String,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }
  store: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Store'
  }
};
```

So how can I find which Stores the User has added the most Products to? This may be obvious, it's late. :-P

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-introduction/) to solve it.
And especially [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline:

```
// aggregate whole `Product` collection
Product.aggregate([
  // count products by `user` and `store` and save result to `products_count`
  {$group: {
    _id: {user_id:"$user", store_id:"$store"},
    products_count: {$sum: 1}
  }},
  // sort by most products count
  {$sort: {products_count: -1}}
])
```

There are also [$limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) and [$skip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) pipelines, that help to paginate all this stuff.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was just reading into the aggregation framework, figured I was getting close. :-P I'll try this out and accept your answer if it all works out as expected. :)

Comment: Ok so this is close. First off, I don't need to group by users, as I'm only looking on a per-user basis. Meaning I can use `{$match: {user: req.params.id}}`, then just `{$group: {_id: "$store"}}` which is working. But, probably as expected, I'm only getting an array of objects containing the Store `_id` and the `product_count` for each. So this is great, except I need to the whole Store. How can I load the whole model instead of just the `_id`..? Thanks again.

Comment: When you're grouping, you're transforming **all** documents in collection into **single** result by `_id` object. In your case it is `store_id`. That is mean mongo will find all documents with the same `store_id` and group all fileds into single one, you can change that filed with operators ($push, $max, $sum ...) but you cannot save them all, because you'll get a **singe** store with grouping results. E.x. you can save `$first` field of **first** document in group, but not everyone. *Hope this helps*